# Plot a Bar Chart based on Row Names

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to plot a dataframe as follows:

```
A  1
C  5
B  4
Z  10
M  7
```

and would it to show the data in the order (i.e. first column in the bar chart is A, second is C, third is B.

I have:

```
ggplot(pc,aes(x=Let,y=Count))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

And it plots it with the order of the Let column.

```
df<-data.frame(c('A','C','B','Z','M'),c(1,5,4,10,7))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to convert `Let` column to `factor` in the order you want to see them and then use `ggplot` command.

```
library(tidyverse)

df$Let <- factor(df$Let, levels = df$Let)
ggplot(df,aes(x=Let,y=Count))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

**data**

```
df<-data.frame(Let = c('A','C','B','Z','M'),Count = c(1,5,4,10,7))
```